# How to see the files in hostPath

Tags: kubernetes

How I can see the files in kuberntes hostPath , I mean:

```
 hostPath:
      # Ensure the file directory is created.
      path: /var/local/aaa    
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
```

How I can enter to `aaa` directory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `hostPath` volume mounts a file or directory from the node's filesystem into the Pod. So you can login/ssh to the node where the pod is scheduled to run and check the files in `/var/local/aaa` path.

Comment: So, Suppose I have a pod, named shell-demo. To get a shell to the running container on this pod, just run:  kubectl exec -it shell-demo -- /bin/bash .  I will get node's filesystem this way , right ?

Comment: You will not get this path `/var/local/aaa`. You will get mount path as defined in the pod spec if that's what you are looking for

Answer (score 2):

The `hostPath` is path on your machine. if you want to have look onto the files or directories then go to the path on machine so in your case it would be `/var/local/aaa`.

For more reference  have a look on this https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath